# how to run the Stored procedure . for inserting the Values

Tags: database

This is my Coding...
If i execute the Stored procedure which means with in the stored procedure
(Normally selecting everything and if i press execute button at top of the menu) 
it is working 
but 
out side 
how can i run the stored procedure.
i tried like this
exec uspGetAddress 'CDB0001','Bevcon Wayors Pvt Ltd','c'
but not working.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @Cuscode varchar(250)
DECLARE @customertName VARCHAR(250) 
DECLARE @custype varchar(250)

DECLARE @Cur_Product CURSOR 
set @Cur_Product= cursor for select CardCode,CardName,CardType  from ocrd 

open @Cur_Product
       fetch next
       from @Cur_Product into @Cuscode,@customertName,@custype
       while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       begin
       insert into custupdate (ccode,cname,ctype) values (@Cuscode,@customertName,@custype)
       fetch next 
       from @Cur_Product into @Cuscode,@customertName,@custype
       end 
       close @Cur_Product
       deallocate @Cur_Product
```

Comment: what is the error code?

Comment: This is not MySQL, tag your question with the appropriate DBMS.

Comment: hi. Alexandre Santos there is no error empty rows are coming. my question is how to run at sql  like exec storedprocedure name like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the Stored Procedure before calling it :

```
Create Procedure uspGetAddress 
 @Cuscode varchar(250),
 @customertName VARCHAR(250) ,
 @custype varchar(250)
As
Begin

DECLARE @Cur_Product CURSOR 
set @Cur_Product= cursor for select CardCode,CardName,CardType  from ocrd 

open @Cur_Product
       fetch next
       from @Cur_Product into @Cuscode,@customertName,@custype
       while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       begin
       insert into custupdate (ccode,cname,ctype) values (@Cuscode,@customertName,@custype)
       fetch next 
       from @Cur_Product into @Cuscode,@customertName,@custype
       end 
       close @Cur_Product
       deallocate @Cur_Product
End
```